# Store values from each loop and use in another function

Tags: jquery, each

I'm trying to compare the aspect ratio of a container against the aspect ratio of a series of images, and add a class portrait or landscape to the images.  Also, I am trying to detect very tall/wide images (like big panoramas) based on a defined tolerance.  I have the basic functionality working [here](http://www.houseofyum.co.uk/static/gallery/index3.html) (the first two images have a 'zoom' button in the top left corner).

Now, I'm trying to split up the function so when I resize the page, the script doesn't calculate the ratios of all the images again (var i_ratio), it just compares these against the new container ratio (var c_ratio).  My development example is [here](http://www.houseofyum.co.uk/static/gallery/index4.html).

I guess my problem is I don't know how to:

- Ensure the 2nd function runs after the first has completed
- Pass the values from i_ratio from the first function to the next

In the dev example there's a console log which shows i_ratio is undefined within the 2nd function, but when you resize the window it appears to get a value - not sure what is happening.

```
// Get window aspect ratio
var container = $('.main');
var c_ratio = container.width() / container.height();
var i_ratio;

function imageRatios() {
  // Get original dimensions of image (IE8+)
  if (this.naturalWidth) {
    i_width = this.naturalWidth;
    i_height = this.naturalHeight;
  } else {
  // Get original dimensions of image with JQuery
    i_width = this.width;
    i_height = this.height;
  }
  i_ratio = i_width / i_height;
  // Don't allow images to get bigger than their original size
  $(this).css('max-width', i_width).css('max-height', i_height);
}

function setClass() {
  console.log('number of images: '+images.length+', i_ratio from imageRatios function: '+i_ratio);
  // Add ratio classes    
  if (c_ratio > i_ratio) {
    $(this).parent('li').removeClass('landscape').addClass('portrait');
  } else {
    $(this).parent('li').removeClass('portrait').addClass('landscape');
  }
  // Identify long/tall panoramas and add zoom button
  tolerance = c_ratio / i_ratio;
  if (tolerance < 0.3 || tolerance > 5) {
    $(this).after('<div class="zoom">&#xf065;</div>');
  } else {
    $(this).remove('.zoom');
  }
  // Show/hide zoomed image
  var img = $(this);
  $(this).next('.zoom').click(function() {
    if (img.siblings('.big_image').size() > 0) {
      $('.big_image').remove();
    } else {
      $(this).after('<div class="big_image"><img src="'+$img.attr('src')+'"></div>');        
    }
  });
}

// Get images
var images = $('.main img');
images.each(function(i) {
  if (this.complete) {
    imageRatios.call(this);
    setClass();
  } else {
    this.onload = imageRatios;
    setClass();
  }
});

// Update ratio class on resize
$(window).on("throttledresize", function() {
  var c_ratio = container.width() / container.height();
  images.each(function() {
    setClass();
  });
});
```

Comment: include the javascript for the functions in your question please

Comment: relevant code is included, thanks.

Comment: Well, you know you can pass arguments to functions right? You seem to be using global variables to share data across functions and that makes your code less flexible and understandable.

Comment: @plalx yeah the js guy at my work said i should do this first too, but i kept breaking it when i tried (i'm just starting out with jquery), do you know any good links which explain how to do this? i couldn't find anything online, maybe i'm searching for the wrong thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issue - this will be untested so you may need to tweak a bit to get it right

- When initializing the images, you are calling setClass immediately after setting an unload handler.  The handler is asynchronous so calling setClass immediately will result the undefined value you are seeing in the console.
- the image ratios are all being stored in the same variable.  You will need to adjust that to store them per image
- when calling setClass, no context is being set when calling setClass so `this` will be the global object

Get Images logic can be adjusted to something like this:

```
// Get images
var images = $('.main img');
images.each(function(i) {
  if (this.complete) {
    imageRatios.call(this, i);
    setClass.call(this, i);   // <== call with image as the context and pass its index
  } else {
    // Wrap the calls to imageRatios & setClass in the callback so
    // they can be called sequentially
    this.onload = function() {
      imageRatios.call(this, i);
      setClass.call(this, i); // <== call with image as the context and pass its index
    };
  }
});
```

Throttled resize can be modified to something like:

```
// Update ratio class on resize
$(window).on("throttledresize", function() {
  c_ratio = container.width() / container.height(); // <== remove var - needs to be available to other functions in this closure (already declared at top)
  // TODO: Just need to update class, not recalculate image ratios on resize
  images.each(function(i) {
    setClass.call(this,i);   // <== call with image as the context and pass its index
  });
});
```

imageRatios to:

```
  var i_ratio = [];         // <== use an array of values indexes will match image indexes

  function imageRatios(i) { // <== change to accept an index
    var i_width, i_height;  // <== declare as local variables

    // Get original dimensions of image (IE8+)
    if (this.naturalWidth) {
      i_width = this.naturalWidth;
      i_height = this.naturalHeight;
    } else {
    // Get original dimensions of image with JQuery
      i_width = this.width;
      i_height = this.height;
    }
    i_ratio[i] = i_width / i_height;  // <== set the ratio using the passed in index
    // Don't allow images to get bigger than their original size
    $(this).css('max-width', i_width).css('max-height', i_height);
  }
```

setClass to:

```
  function setClass(i) {  // <== Change to accept an index
    var tolerance; // <== Declare as local variable
    console.log('number of images: '+images.length+', i_ratio from imageRatios function: '+i_ratio);
    // Add ratio classes    
    if (c_ratio > i_ratio[i]) { // <== Use the index to get the right ratio
      $(this).parent('li').removeClass('landscape').addClass('portrait');
    } else {
      $(this).parent('li').removeClass('portrait').addClass('landscape');
    }
    // Identify long/tall panoramas and add zoom button
    tolerance = c_ratio / i_ratio[i]; // <== Use the index to get the right ration
    if (tolerance < 0.3 || tolerance > 5) {
      $(this).after('<div class="zoom">&#xf065;</div>');
    } else {
      $(this).remove('.zoom');
    }
    // Show/hide zoomed image
    var img = $(this);
    $(this).next('.zoom').click(function() {
      if (img.siblings('.big_image').size() > 0) {
        $('.big_image').remove();
      } else {
        $(this).after('<div class="big_image"><img src="'+$img.attr('src')+'"></div>');        
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: thankyou! i learned so much from this code. there were a couple of syntax errors which i was able to fix.  do you want me to update your answer with the corrected code? not sure about SO etiquette :) if not you can find the working code here http://www.houseofyum.co.uk/static/gallery/index5.html

Comment: I just made a couple of updates maybe I caught them?  If not, post them here and I can update. Check my edit history to make sure we caught the same issues.

Comment: @daviestar - on your site, your big_image logic is failing at this line: `$(this).after('<div class="big_image"><img src="'+$img.attr('src')+'"></div>');` : `$img is not defined`

Comment: you got them all, apart from in your first code snippet - close this.onload with }

Comment: @daviestar - updated. thanks! (and check my previous comment)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36966/discussion-between-daviestar-and-dc5)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with the undefined value comes from this code

```
images.each(function (i) {
    if (this.complete) {
        imageRatios.call(this);
        setClass();
    } else {
        this.onload = imageRatios;
        setClass();
    }
});
```

That sets the onload callback of each image to be `imageRatios` and then calls `setClass()` It does not however wait until the `onload` event has been fired to continue on to `setClass` try something like this

```
images.each(function (i) {
    if (this.complete) {
        imageRatios.call(this);
        setClass();
    } else {
        this.onload = function () {
            imageRatios();
            setClass();
        };
    }
});
```

which will call `imageRatios()` and then `setClass()` in that order when the `onload` event is fired for the image

Comment: thanks, this makes sense.  however instead of 'undefined' the console now says Not a Number.  I have updated my example with your code here: http://www.houseofyum.co.uk/static/gallery/index4.html